# What is the value of CLOUDAMQP_URL?

Tags: android, rabbitmq

I want to use RabbitMQ with android. I am new with this concept.
    can you please tell what is the value of "CLOUDAMQP_URL" in this following snippet? or where can i find URL?

```
 private void setupConnectionFactory() {
        String uri = "CLOUDAMQP_URL";
        try {
            factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false); 
            factory.setUri(uri);
        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a placeholder for you to fill in with your RabbitMQ connection string.

I'm guessing this is example code that assumes you are using http://cloudamqp.com as the RabbitMQ hosting service.

whoever wrote the example wants you to sign up for an account (they have a free one). once you do that, you will receive a RabbitMQ connection string URL for your RabbitMQ server. That connection string will go in here.

The URL will generally look like this:

`String uri = "amqp://<user>:<password>@<server>:<port>/<vhost>";`